# Is it appropriate to use link texts instead of full URLs on a resume?

Tags: resume

A HTML link with link text (anchor) would be useless if the resume is printed out.

Like this: [Google](http://google.com) instead of just the URL http://google.com.

In this era, can we safely assume that our links will be accessible and won't it cost me if I use link text?

Comment: This is usually called "anchor text" and is standard for electronic documents (link "masking" is usually refering to something more nefarious). In HTML you can also arrange that print versions include the URL text when printed out, e.g. see here for a CSS code to do that https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/print-url-after-links/

Comment: The bigger question is why do you want to include a link?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I would like to include links to relevant work and a personal website.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume your resume will be printed out and read (and sorted for interest) in printed form. Offering URIs may be useful if someone wants to follow up on something after you've gotten past the first few layers of screening, but if they aren't visible in plaintext they may get lost before reaching the person who would be interested.

Also remember that some folks may be reading this with assistive technology. I don't know how sophisticated tools for blind users are these days; I would *hope* they'd be able to handle hypertext by now but I'm not sure I'd want to count on that.

Or offer both a "live" version and a plaintext-friendly version?

Comment: Understood. I'm in the software industry so I thought it might be savvy to mask the URIs. I shall follow your advice nonetheless; it seems the safest path.

Comment: So am I... but don't count on the interview process using current technology. The old line about the cobbler's kids going barefoot still carries entirely too much truth -- and paper is still easier to work with when trying to compare and contrast fifteen documents which may have little in common with each other.

Comment: As regards those viewing electronic versions using assistive technology, it's  _generally_ best to go with anchor text as a, for example, screen reader, will announce that is a link and can then just say "Google" or otherwise will have to announce a link and then read out "http-colon-forwardslash-forwardslash-google-dot-com"

Comment: @Steve I'm in the software industry as well. The last time I looked for a job, every interview I got came from handing recruiters paper resumes, and even after emailing a PDF on request, whoever interviewed me always had a paper copy in hand. My best advice is to display the URLs on your resume, and make them links.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to the other great answers here, you could always link the text in your resume, but also place a footnote label next to it, like this:
[Google<sup>[1]</sup>](http://www.google.com)

Then in a footnote area, either in the page footer or at the end of the document, include a line like:
`[1] http://www.google.com`

Not only does this provide accessibility <del>if</del>when the resume is printed out, but it also provides extra transparency when it *is* being viewed electronically (for those that aren't already savvy enough to know how to reveal link targets themselves).

Answer (score 3):

When generating a CV/Resume assume it is never in the format you want.

Some companies will convert to the file format they want. Others will automatically pull the info they find into a database. Many will ask you to cut and paste the paragraphs into their web form, one text box at a time.

Make sure that the required info makes it through these processes. A URL that is so ugly and long that you want to hide behind anchor text, may limit the number of people who will be willing to type it out when they are only given an image of the resume.

There is no need to make links to the companies you have worked for. Also few will click on github or other sites that will store your portfolio, unles they have specifically asked for those links.

A new problem I have run into is that my corporate email is now configured to mangle all external URLs so that they can't be clicked, and that you have to carefully cut the good part so that you can paste it into the browser.

Answer (score 2):

> In this era, can we safely assume that our links will be accessible
>   and won't it cost me if I use link text?

**No. You cannot assume that.**

Even in this era, resumes are very often converted to PDFs and/or printed or go through other steps that could remove a hyperlink. In my experience many recruiters and HR groups don't take the steps necessary to preserve all formatting aspects of submitted documents.

Why assume anything and take that chance? Far better to use the full URL http://google.com to ensure that your links are readable in all cases.